# Checkmark for obtained badge overflows for badge with long names

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, badge-progress

When selecting a next tag badge to track, and choosing a category, e.g. Silver, you first see badges you already obtained. When the badge name is long, the checkmark overflows the container:

[image]

This happens in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like having been fixed:

[image]

I guess this happened by specifying a value for the CSS property `word-break`:

[image]